# MOS Differential Pair - Transistor Mismatch

Tags: mosfet

[image]

I have the following,
[image]

I'm not too sure how to proceed. Usually, I can just split the circuit down the middle due to symmetry, but since there's a transistor mismatch, I can't even do that. 
Do I really have to draw the small-signal model for the entire thing?

Comment: *Do I really have to draw the small-signal model for the entire thing?* Only if you can reason that the symmetry still applies when there is mismatch, you don't have to. But it is easy to reason that when there is mismatch the tail of the diffpair, P, isn't at a constant voltage, it will have a signal. So yes, you need the complete small signal equivalent. But think for a moment, what influences the CMM gain? How is that related to the signal on node P? If there was no mismatch is there a signal on node P?

Comment: Actually, I think even if there was no mismatch, I wouldn't be able to split it. M3 would always need a certain VDS for it to stay in saturation and act as the tail current source, so since we would always need a voltage Vds3, we can't split it up.

Comment: *M3 would always need a certain VDS for it to stay in saturation* True but not the issue. Draw the full small signal equivalent circuit, it will be symmetrical around P. That means if Vin is fully differential (zero commonmode voltage) then there will be no signal on P meaning that M3 will behave as a pure current source. The Vds you talk about is **DC**. In the small signal model, M3 will be a resistor (Rout of M3) to ground. Only when there is a CMM input signal and/or there is mismatch in the diff.pair will there be AC across this resistor.